# .NET Core create process without a job

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate a Win app (.NET Framework 4.6.1) to .NET Core 3 in order to run it on different systems. 
The problem is that to solve an old bug in my app I had to use CreateProcess (win api) instead of Process.Start() because of the CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB flag, is there something similar I can use in .NET Core to spawn a process without being its parent?

Comment: Why not using a Task?

Comment: What does the process need to achieve? There is `IHostedService` is .NET Core that supports background processes.

Comment: My app is a kind of a watchdog which need to start different processes that not related to my app. So Tasks, HostedServices are irrelevant